# Archive list for custom post type categories

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I am using a recipe plugin that uses a custom post type of 'recipe'. I currently have multiple lists of recipes from each category on a page. I am trying to get the title of each category list to link to an archive list of those posts within each category. This is not working, and I'm not sure if I need to create a new archive template, or if I can do it within this code.

```
<ul class="subcats-list">
            <h2 class="subcats-title"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(39); ?>" title="No Cook"><?php echo get_cat_name(39); ?></a></h2>
                <?php
                $recipes = new WP_Query();
                $recipes->query('showposts=5&orderby=rand&cat=39&post_type=recipe');

                while ($recipes->have_posts()) : $recipes->the_post(); ?>
                  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul><!-- subcat -->
```

NOTE: the title for each category list does currently link to the category archive page, but there are no posts listed. Just a black archive page.

Comment: What happens if you take out the parameter 'cat=39' ?

Comment: the cat=39 is used to display 5 posts from that category in the list. I need the title of that list to link to a category archive list. It does go to the category archive page, but nothing is there. it's just blank.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you create the link with your category '39'? Is it a custom taxonomy?

Here's the test i just did and it works fine:

In `functions.php` i created the custom post type '**recipe**':

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_recipe' );
function create_recipe() {
    register_post_type( 'recipe',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Recipes' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Recipe' )
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'menu_position' => 4,
            'query_var' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor')

        )
    );
}
```

Then i created a custom taxonomy element to get some categories related to this custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cate_livro', 0 );
function register_cate_livro() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'cate-recipe',
        array( 'recipe' ),
        array(
            'public' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Categorias' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Categoria' )
            ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => 'cate-livro'
        )
    );
}
```

I nammed it '**cate-recipe**'.

I wrote 3 news posts under '**recipe**' in the admin and created 2 custom categories '**cate-1**' and '**cate-2**'.

Then using your code, i loaded the posts from the custom post type. It works fine but doesnt take in account the custom taxonomy parameter. So here's how i made it in the end:

```
<ul class="subcats-list">
    <h2 class="subcats-title"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(12); ?>" title="No Cook"><?php echo get_cat_name(39); ?></a></h2>
        <?php
        $recipes = new WP_Query();
        $args = array(
            'showposts'     =>  5,  
            'orderby'       =>  'rand',
            'post_type'     =>  'recipe',
            'tax_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'cate-recipe',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'cate-1'
                )
            )
        );
        $recipes->query($args);

        while ($recipes->have_posts()) : $recipes->the_post(); ?>
          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

</ul><!-- subcat -->
```

I'm using the '`tax_query`' parameter to query the posts from my custom taxonomy '**cate-recipe**' with the term '**cate-1**', that i created in the admin.

And it loads just the posts that have this "special category".

Hope this helps, let me know if it suits your needs.